# R: Error opening file(corrupted data) using fread

Tags: r, error-handling

I run into issue with opening a large file using fread.

`df <- fread("userprofile.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")`

```
In fread("userprofile.csv", encoding = "UTF-8") :
  Stopped early on line 342637. Expected 77 fields but found 81. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line:
```

Edit1:
`df <- fread("userprofile.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", fill=TRUE)`
This gave me [R Session Aborted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcM0f.png)

Is there any alternative to open a large file? or handle this error?

Comment: Have you tried `df <- fread("userprofile.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", fill=TRUE)` as suggested by the error output?

Comment: my experience is that you lose or gain some columns during the process. Try using with `fill = TRUE` as suggested above. If this fails, manually inspect this row of data (notepad++ can be better than excel for this) to see if there's a pattern in the data you need to account for

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I have used ```fill = TURE```This gave me "R Session Aborted" and I have to restart R.